# Unexplained massive rmagick temporarily file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, disk-space-utilization, tmp, rmagick

### Problem

We recently ran into a situation whereby some of our server instances were suddenly running out of disc space, evidenced by below graph:

[image: this fast]

The reason for running out of disc space is a single `/tmp/magick-???` file, that grows into a 4GB monster within minutes.

### System setup

To give some background into our system, we run a big rails app which uses `mini_magick 4.7.1` and `carrier_wave ~0.11.0` to perform product image uploads via background jobs.

### Observations

We naturally expected image uploads to accrue some temporary files during the server's life span, which could be salvaged by running `CarrierWave.clean_cached_files!` periodically.

Is there something we could've missed?